# Insert row without reloading table

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

Hello i have tableview with many objects in it. If i want to add one row in it without reloading whole table. Because there are some process in cell. Anybody can help ?

Comment: Sample code: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableViewUpdates/Listings/ReadMe_txt.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do it in 2 ways -

```
[tableView beginUpdates];
[tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:newResults withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
[tableView endUpdates];
```

or

```
[tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:newResults withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

here `newResults` are an `NSArray` of `NSIndexPath` which you need to create. Then the new rows are inserted (with some animation or without) at those rows.

Comment: Why are you using `withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone` in both examples?

Answer (score 3):

Use below delegate method

```
- (void)insertRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation
```