# Reload one Row without animation (reloadRowsAtIndexPaths). Picture inside

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

In my Example i 've got 2 Sections with 1 Row at the Start. It someone clicks on the first row of a section i insert all other rows of this section:

```
[tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexArray withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
```

This works fine, but i need to update the Background of the first row. This works too, but i need to relayout the first row. I have tried setNeedsDisplay and setNeedsLayout, but it don't worked. A reloadDate shows the right background, but it destroys the sliding effect.

I know that i can update a Row with one of this:

```
[tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:indexArrayReload withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
[tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:indexArrayReload withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

But they change the hight of the Row temporary. I need a real fading effect or a reload without animation.

Here is the Picture of the Situation:

[image]

Edit: I 've made a video:

[This shows the Problem!](http://vimeo.com/59985827)

Comment: I still don't got a solution for this problem ;(
Is it maybe the false way to implement this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution:

```
[tableView beginUpdates];
...
[tableView endUpdates];
```

[I fond it in another thread.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8655310/1862913)